# Append expression to 'Select by expression' window using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I have a PyQGIS script that creates expressions and I would like to append them to the  'Select by expression' window. The script is executed from the Python console. At the moment the script copies expressions to the clipboard and then I paste the expressions manually. However, I wonder if it's possible to append text directly from the script.

The script:

```
# Script that is supposed to help with selection of features
# with certain attributes
# 1. Make your selection
# 2. Run script
# 3. Point at the feature of interest, observe that
#    marker has changed.
# Script will then look for an attribute that is ~NULL.
# This attribute value is then copied to clipboard as 
# an expression ready to use for further processing

from qgis.gui import QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QApplication

attribs = ['VAGBETECKN', 'HUVLEDNAMN', 'NYLEDNAMN','VAGNR', 'GATUNAMN', ]
attribs.append('RLID')  # default, always exists

def onFeatureIdentified(f):
    #print('Feature RLID: {}'.format(f['RLID']))
    for attrib in attribs:
        val = f[attrib]
        if val != NULL:
            if not isinstance(val, str):
                val = str(val)
            #print('Value found. {}:{}'.format(attrib, val))
            break

    #print('Using: {} = {} for RLID {}'.format(attrib, val, f['RLID']))
    s = "(\"" + attrib + "\"='" + val + "')"
    clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
    clipboard.setText(s)
    print('To clipboard: {}'.format(s))

layer = iface.activeLayer()
mc=iface.mapCanvas()
mapTool = QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature(mc)
mapTool.setLayer(layer)
mc.setMapTool(mapTool)
mapTool.featureIdentified.connect(onFeatureIdentified)
```